# Webserver doesn't show actual file

Tags: php, server, webserver, refresh

I have an annoying problem with a webserver, btw. I don't even know if it is him.

I upload a test.php with simply

```
echo "asdasdasdasd";
```

in it .. i call it with the browser and then update the test.php to

```
echo "qqq";
```

.. then I press F5 .. but the server still shows the output of the old test.php. When I wait 3-5 min and press F5 then, the actual test.php is shown.

I tried with different browsers and with cache completely disabled, but still the same effect. I have never seen something like that before, can someone help me? It is very annoying to have to wait for every "refresh."

Comment: f5 just reloads from cache. try shift-f5, which forces a "fetch from server" reload.

Comment: Maybe there is a cache like Varnish running on the webserver.

Comment: This could also be opcache in aggressive mode.

Comment: I have tried shift+f5 all the time, disabled all browser-cache.. nothing :/
@jpaljasma: how do you mean that?

Comment: Check your opcache.revalidate_freq setting http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php but again, you didn't say anything about your environment.

Comment: What if you add a dummy url argument, like test.php?test=1 and change the number each time?

Comment: i have tried `opcache_invalidate('test.php', true);` now, but with no effort.
It is php.5.6 .. hostes says _"Global-Rocket-Cache" (APCu/ZendOPcache)_

Comment: that with a `?test=1` worked :) .. thank you :) .. but is there a way to get that away, too? .. I mean, that startet happening 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

i finaly found a way to handle this behavior.. I switched my PHP from 5.6 down to 5.5. :) .. in 5.5. there is no opcache.. problem solved :P